# I have a problem with splitting up my Java program into separate methods within the same class, could I have some advice on how to go about it?

Tags: java, arrays, checkbox, methods, bluej

I was given the task of splitting my program which which allows the user to enter an array of numbers and after an odd number between 1 and 10 to check whether the odd number is a factor of each of the 5 numbers in the array. I keep on trying out different ways but none seem to work. Could someone help me out or send a sample of how I should sort it? This is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CheckboxExample{  
    public static void main(String args[])  {  
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
        new CheckboxExample();  // links to checkbox class
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[] = new int[10]; 
        System.out.println ("Please enter 10 random numbers"); // prompts the user to enter 10 numbers
        int num; // declares variable num
        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                array[i] = s.nextInt(); // array declaration
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println ("You have an error");
        }

        System.out.println ("Please enter an odd number between 1 and 10");

        try{
            num = s.nextInt ();
            if (num % 2 == 0){
                do{
                    System.out.println ("\nYour number is even, enter an odd one");
                    num = s.nextInt ();
                }while (num % 2 == 0);
            } 

            if (num < 0 | num > 10){
                do{  
                    System.out.println ("Your number is outside of the range, try again");
                    num = s.nextInt ();  
                }while (num < 0 | num > 10);
            } 

            for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
                if (array[i] % num  == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your number is a factor of " + array[i] );
                } 
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println ("error");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: A Java method name should be a verb-noun combination.  Some examples, looking at your code, would be readNumbers, readOddNumber, checkIfFactor.

Answer (score 0):

A method should ideally be responsible for one task. In your case you should think about the different things your code try to do and organize them in a sense that each of the methods you call does one thing of the list of things you try to do.
As an example: As far as I understand your code does the following things:

1. Read an array of 10 values
2. Read an odd number
3. Verify the number is odd
4. Verify the number is in range
5. Calculate if the number is a factor of one of the 10 numbers in the array

Now one possible approach would be to separate your code in 5 methods that do exactly these things.

At first you call the method that reads the 10 numbers.
Then you call the method to read the odd number.
3. and 4. are actually part of reading the number, since you need to retry on an invalid input, so you could write your method for inputting the odd number in a way that it uses the methods for verifying the input.
Finally when you have all the valid input, you call the method which produces your result (ie. if the number is a factor of the numbers in the list).

A general outlier for your code could look like:

```java
public class CheckboxExample {  
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
        new CheckboxExample();  // links to checkbox class
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[] = readInputArray();
        int number = readOddValue();
        calculateFactors(array, number);
    }

    private int[] readInputArray() {...}

    private int readOddValue() {...}

    private void calculateFactors(int[] array, int number) {...}
    
    //additional methods used by readOddValue which verify if the value is actually odd

}
```

Please note that this is just one way to split your code into methods and there are several ways to design and implement each of these methods.